# Mongodb: list all values for an indexed field quickly

Tags: mongodb, morphia

In mongodb I want to be able to rapidly list all index values.  for instants lets say I have numerous collections of FOO:

```
public class Foo{

   @ID
   private ObjectID id;
   @Indexed
   private List<String> bars;
   @Indexed List<String> bazs;
   ...
}
```

There may be repeats in bars and baz, such that iterating through ever foo and looking at the bars list would be inefficient, since I would be spending most of my time looking at repeats.

If I want to quickly list all 'bars' values without having to look at each Foo object can I do that?  Since they are indexed there must be a table somewhere with all the indexes listed in an easily iterated manner.  However, I can't seem to find a mongodb command to do this?  or better yet a morphia command since I'm using java to interface with mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `distinct`, which should work for lists / arrays as well. MongoDB will use an index if one is available.

Unfortunately this feature [isn't yet implemented in Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/219), but you can do the following with the Java driver:

```
DBCollection c = collection;
List bars = c.distinct("bars");
```

For a more complex example see the [unit test for this feature](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/com/mongodb/DBCollectionTest.java#L324).

Comment: is this distinct happening on the java side or the mongo side?  sounds like it's java side?

Comment: Plain MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/